# Conditional regex in vim?

Tags: regex, vim, conditional-statements

Is it possible to do conditional regex (like the one described in http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) in Vim?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim regex does not have this feature, so you will need to use a bit of repetition to create the same behaviour:

```
/\(\%(condition\)\@=then\|\%(condition\)\@!else\)
```

Note that you have to use the condition twice in the Vim version and the lookahead/lookbehind must always be the opposite in the then/else parts otherwise your regex will not be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Not natively, however if you have +perl in vim you should be able to use

```
:perldo s/search/replace/
```

Answer (score 3):

The [vim docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#perl-patterns) state that vim's regexes don't support the conditional expressions (in a section comparing vim's pattern support with perl's):

> Finally, these constructs are unique to Perl:
>   - execution of arbitrary code in the regex:  (?{perl code})
>   - conditional expressions:  (?(condition)true-expr|false-expr)