# How to remove command from latex file using search and replace in Vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I want to do a search and replace in a latex file as follows:

```
:%s/\\todo{.*}/\1/gc
```

That should transform texts like "`abc \todo{def} ghi`" into "`abc def ghi`". It happens that when the `\todo{...}` command is inside another one, vim tries to match the second (closing) bracket with that of the outer command. For instance, "`abc \textbf{def \todo{ghi} jkl}`" becomes "`abc \textbf{def ghi} jkl`" when it should be "`abc \textbf{def ghi jkl}`".

Is there a way to match the corresponding bracket?

**Edit:**

Sorry for not pointing that out before. It would be nice if it could match exactly the correspondent bracket since there can be commands inside as well as ouside the `\todo{...}` command.

**Edit:**

```
"abc \todo{def \textbf{ghi} jkl}" -> "abc def \textbf{ghi} jkl"
"abc \textbf{def \todo{ghi} jkl}" -> "abc \textbf{def ghi jkl}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Non Recursive**

Tell it to match anything but {}s:

```
:%s/\\todo{\([^{}]\+\)}/\1/
```

**Recursive**

The Vim regex language doesn't support the [conditional regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901240/conditional-regex-in-vim/2901319#2901319) that would be required to match patterns in the way you suggest.

But, you can use an external language like perl to do so:

```
:perldo $_ =~ s/\\todo ({( (?: [^{}]*+ | (?1) )* )}) /\2/gx
```

For more information about recursive regex's [checkout this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes/4843579#4843579). I also found [We's Puzzling Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2005/02/20/377025.aspx) helpful in sussing these kinds of regexes out.

Comment: It should be noted that this (or any other regex solution) will be problematic if there are further commands *inside* `\todo` instead of around it.

Comment: And comments, and multiline blocks, and... :) If there isn't a refactoring tool to make the changes freitass needs to make, I'm hard pressed to think of other solutions beyond hand editing, regexes, and writing a full program. The parser will only tell you when your source doesn't parse - which is helpful, but it certainly won't make the changes for you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want your regex to be greedy. See answer [How can I make my match non greedy in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305853/how-can-i-make-my-match-non-greedy)

In your case this should do the trick:

```
:%s/\v\\todo\{(.{-})\}/\1/gc
```

Answer (score 0):

[Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns) No.

We can support one level of nesting as follows:

We want to pair curly braces inside the `\todo{}`.
So we have to match as many `[^{}]` and `{[^{}]*}` as possible.

```
:%:s/\\todo{\(\([^{}]\|{[^{}]*}\)*\)}/\1/
```

We add an extra `\(\)` to store the entire thing in `\1`.